# How to make Visual Studio 2013 show unhandled exception message?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, exception, visual-studio-2013

I throw this error in my C++ program and don't handle it:

```
throw std::runtime_error("X failed because " + my_string);
```

I compile and run it with Visual Studio 2013, and get the following error:

> Unhandled exception at 0x7617C42D in bla.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::runtime_error at memory location 0x009FEA98.

How can I see the message "X failed because ..." without handling the error in the code?

Comment: Is there a `catch` block for the exception you're throwing?  If not, then of course you get the "Unhandled Exception" message.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I want to use the Visual Studio debug interface to see the `what()` of an unhandled exception, not just to know that there was an unhandled exception.

Comment: In Visual C++, unhandled exceptions are routed to the default unexpected handler, which in turn calls `terminate()`. As far as I can tell, the thrown exception object isn't made available to the unexpected handler at that point, so there's no way to determine what its contents might be.

Comment: I've made a feature request to VS team. You can vote it up and track it here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/366698/ability-to-examine-exception-object-on-unhandled-e.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to figure out which exception caused your program to terminate *while debugging*, you can simply Break then navigate the call stack to see where the exception is thrown.

If you are in the Debug mode, the top of the call stack will probably point at `_CxxThrowException`. In that case, you *could* inspect its argument `pExceptionObject` and even add something like `((std::exception*)pExceptionObject)->what()` to the watch list. However, this relies on a few assumptions that are not always valid.

It is really easier to add a `catch (std::exception& e)` and inspect the error there.

Answer (score 1):

You could easily create an exception wrapper, that outputs the exception's `what()` to the debug output. While this would not require you to add catch blocks to handle the immediate location that your exceptions are thrown, it would require you to wrap all your throw calls with the wrapper class. For example:

```
class ExceptionOutputDebug : public std::exception
{
    public:
    ExceptionOutputDebug(const std::exception& e)
    {
        OutputDebugString(e.what());
        OutputDebugString("\n");
        if (1) // avoids C4702 (unreachable code)
            throw e;
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
throw ExceptionOutputDebug(std::runtime_error("Die"));
```

Will then output to the debug output window:

```
Die
First-chance exception at 0x76CAC42D in blah.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::exception at memory location 0x019EFEBC.
```

This might be useful if your program is throwing a lot of exceptions, and have disabled the debugger breaking on them. It could also be useful if running outside the debugger, and `OutputDebugString` calls were replaced with some external logging mechanism (could be as simple as `printf` for console applications).